# get / fetch data from boolean array - Firestore Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[firestoredatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA3pX.png)

Hi! i want to get data from an array of boolean from my firestore data base, if i run this code:

```
 Log.d("firestore", String.valueOf(document.getData()));
```

I get this result:

{nombre=AVL, boolArray=[true, false, false]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.get("boolArray")` should return a `List<Boolean>` type object.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getData()` will return a `Map` which in term contains two other maps. In the first case, the value is of type `String` while in the second case, the value is an `Array`. But if you are using `document.get("boolArray")`, as Doug said, even if we know that data is stored as an array, the data is returned as a `List<Boolean>`.

If you want to read more, you can also see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001490/firestore-query-all-the-elements-in-array-in-android).