# "No setter/field for field found on class"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app in Android Studio, which connects to a Cloud Firestore database. In the database I have the following structure:

```
Myclass
  - name = "test"
  - subclass
     - 0 = "String 1"
     - 1 = "String 2"
```

The class itself is declared like this (irrelevant bits removed):

```
public class Myclass {

    private String name;
    private String[] subclass;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Chart() {}

    //GETTERS
    public String getName()     { return this.name; }

    // SETTERS
    public void setSubclass(String[] thisSubclass)    { this.subclass = thisSubclass; }

}
```

In the activity, the Myclass object is set up like this (again, irrelevant bits removed):

```
public class MyclassActivity  {
    DocumentReference docRef;
    Myclass myItem;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Set up database connection, read in itemId etc...
       // ...omitted for clarity...    

        docRef = databaseRef.collection("myclass").document(itemId);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        myItem = document.toObject(Myclass.class);
                    }
                }
         }
}
```

This reads in the Myclass object, with the name set correctly, but the subclass object doesn't get set up - it's still null.

In the debug console there's the following message:

```
No setter/field for subclass found on class path.to.app.Myclass
```

The 'setSubclass' function is greyed out, as if it's never used. I'm sure the problem is something obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Why don't you try making your subclass field a List rather than array?
```private List<String> subclass;```

Comment: Tried that - it didn't make any difference. Unless I was supposed to do something with the data structure in the database?

Comment: Is this a key value pair?
- subclass
     - 0 = "String 1"
     - 1 = "String 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your model class. First one would be the name of the constructor which is different than the name of the class and should be the same. And the second, for the `subclass` field you have only defined the setter but without a getter.

Your `Myclass` class should look like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private String[] subclass;

    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(String name, String[] subclass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subclass = subclass;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String[] getSubclass() { return subclass; }
}
```

Setters are not not required. If there is no setter for a JSON property, the Firebase client will set the value directly onto the field, that's why is called idiomatic. If you need them explicitly in your code, just add the following setters to your model class like this:

```
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

public void setSubclass(String[] subclass) { this.subclass = subclass; }
```

Regarding the use of arrays in the Cloud Firestore database, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001490/firestore-query-all-the-elements-in-array-in-android)**.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to a List (so List<String> instead of String[]) and added a Getter, and it worked.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem right now its that your class name must be the same than the constructor. Also you need to add a `getter` to your `subclass` parameter.

```
public class Chart {

   private String name;
   private String[] subclass;

   public Chart() {
   //Default empty constructor, required for Firebase.
   }

   public Chart(String name, String[] subclass) {
       this.name = name;
       this.subclass = subclass;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public String[] getSubclass() {
      return subclass;
   }
}
```

In other hand, you don't need to add the setters. They are not required. Firebase will set the value into the field. But you should add them if you're going to interact with the class from outside.

There will be some cases where you want to have different names on your parameters, maybe because you want to follow a camelCase nomenclature or something. If that's the case you can use the annotation `@PropertyName` to provide a different name in your database and keep your model as you want. For example:

```
public class Chart {

   @PropertyName("name")
   private String mName;
   @PropertyName("subclass")
   private String[] mSubclass;

   public Chart() {
   }

   @PropertyName("name")
   public String getmName() {
      return mName;
   }

   @PropertyName("subclass")
   public String[] getmSubclass() {
      return mSubclass;
   }
}
```