# How to add multiple image URLs to the same field in Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to coding and I am looking for a solution to add multiple image `URLs` (the images are selected from the gallery) to the same field in Cloud Firestore so as I could retrieve and display them later in a `ViewPager`.

I have been trying to find the solution, but with no luck.

Please, help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by storing json array in cloud_firestore image_url_key
{"array": ["url1","url2","url3"]}

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can achieve this. The first one would be to store those urls in a `map`. In this case the database structure should look this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- collection
         |
         --- document
               |
               --- urls
                    |
                    --- url : "http://..."
                    |
                    --- url : "http://..."
```

But because the urls contain characters that aren't allowed to be used in the keys, you'll need to use an encoded version of the URL as the key (typically just strips the illegal characters, but a hashcode is also common) and then use the full URL as the value.

Because from 13th august it is possible to **[filter data in Cloud Firestore based on array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001490/firestore-query-all-the-elements-in-array-in-android)** using `whereArrayContains()`, the second solution would be to store those urls in an array. In this case the database structure should look this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- collection
         |
         --- document
               |
               --- urls: ["http://...", "http://..."]
```

Comment: Hi Giho Kim! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.