# GCP Firestore array-container unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Running a compound query against a Firestore collection using `array-contains` as specified in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

Here is my query:

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
  .where('organization.id', '==', orgId)
  .where('type', '==', type)
  .where('employeeIds', 'array-contains', employeeId)
  .get()
```

This will not return a match. Do you know if `array-contains` can only be used alone and not with other `AND` filters?

There is little clear documentation and eaxmples on this.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will not return a match. Do you know if array-contains can only be used alone and not with other AND filters?

There is nothing wrong in combining `array-contains` with other equality `==` operators. You can use **only** one time `array-contains` but you can chain as many equality functions as you want. Your query should work perfectly fine if your `db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)` points to right place and the `orgId`, `type` and `employeeId` hold the right value. Moreover, in most of the cases that kind of query doesn't work because many developers try to order the results. In such cases, rememeber that an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454763/unexpected-behavior-when-query-by-wherearraycontains/53457251) is required.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. These are exactly my thoughts also. What I found was that when I defined the db.collection to a variable and then build additional wheres conditionally (e.g if(this==that) ref.where(... add array-contains) then the query doesn't work. New behavior and need to get used to this. THanks

Comment: You're very welcome. Please also note that Firestore queries are immutable, which means that you cannot change the properties of an existing query. If you change the value by using `array-contains` or `==`, it becomes a new query. So you'll always need to store all new calls into a Query object