# Firestore showing deleted documents and fields

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have deleted some documents and some fields in one of the collections, and when I launch my app the firestore code still is able to fetch the old documents and the old fields and is not showing the newly added fields. I have deleted and added fields using firebase console and not programmatically, is that an issue?

**Now when I update data from my app, the updated data is showing up in my app but not in the firebase console**

Is there a problem with the console? Or is it the firestore rules that's causing this

```
 db.collection("chats").whereArrayContains("users",userId.toString())
        .orderBy("time_last",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener{
        snapshot,e  ->  //my implementation }
```

this is the specific document call.

```
db.collection("chats").document("GsGFZGaQnT2ypp1rvfAx").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            it->
            Log.i("chats document","$it")
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code that produces that behavior.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated the question. I have even tried calling the specific document using the document id but I am still not getting the updated values, do you think there is a problem with my firebase project?

Comment: Have you tried to use onFailure to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo onFailure doesn't have any output. There's no error returned.

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on user's device?

Comment: Yes sir, the internet connection is there Or else some of the images in my app won't be loading.

Comment: Have you created the corresponding [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454763/unexpected-behavior-when-query-by-wherearraycontains/53457251)?

Comment: @AlexMamo the logcat gave me an error the first time itself, so I've created the index a long back.

Comment: @AlexMamo I recently changed my DNS to use openDNS, now I changed it back to use google DNS which was the one that I used previously. Now everything is back to normal. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore caches your db on your local machine (if enabled). This is used as a temporary fallback if you haven't a connection.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Have a look at [How to clear Firestore persistence data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929728/how-to-clear-firestore-persistence-data)

Comment: I've tried this but still showing the old values.

Comment: I've updated the question. I have even tried calling the specific document using the document id but I am still not getting the updated values, do you think there is a problem with my firebase project?

Comment: changed my DNS server to google DNS it worked.